# Testing Angular Service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to test a service and having difficulty with the set up. My initial set up is

```
  beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [ServiceWeAreTesting,,
                { provide: DependencyOne, useClass: MockDependencyOne },
                { provide: DependencyTwo, useClass: MockDependencyTwo },
                { provide: DependencyThree, useClass: MockDependcyThree },
            ]
        });
    });

 beforeEach(() => {
        serviceTest = TestBed.get(ServiceWeAreTesting);
        spyOn(serviceTest, "testFuncOne").and.callThrough();
        spyOn(serviceTest, "testFuncTwo").and.callThrough();
      });
```

I am trying to test that in serviceTest -  testFuncOne, testFuncTwo is being called. But these functions are being called in the constructor so what I think the issue is  the spyOn is being set too late. How would I set the spy on?

Edit:

```
beforeEach(() => {
        mockDependencyThree = TestBed.get(DependencyThree)
        spyOn(mockDependencyThree, "function").and.callThrough();
        serviceTest = TestBed.get(ServiceWeAreTesting);
        spyOn(serviceTest, "testFuncOne").and.callThrough();
        spyOn(serviceTest, "testFuncTwo").and.callThrough();
      });
```

Then in my test I am doing

```
  it('mockDependencyThree function call test', () => {
        expect(mockDependencyThree.function).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
```

The function should've been called when the original service got created.

Comment: Spying on the service under test makes no sense. What you need to spy on is the dependencies of the service under test. Create spy objects using jasmine, provide them using `useValue` and then get the service under test and check that the spied methods of the dependencies have been called as expected.

Comment: So I wasn't originally spying on the service but I had written a test something like ('values loaded') and I expected values to not be empty but it came up as empty. So I wanted to make sure that the functions being called to load the values were being called. I am fairly new to unit testing but let's say in my example DependencyThree , I spy on a function that it would call. How would I do that before the service is declared?

Comment: By creating an instance of MockDependcyThree and spying on its method, or by creating a completely fake instance of DependencyThree using jasmine.createSpyObj(), and providing this  instance using `{ provide: DependencyThree, useValue: theSpiedDependencyThreeInstance }`

Comment: Please look at the edited comment above.